Hiding "display values", the numbers 45396 are showing where there is no data entered into the cell. How do I hide this?
enter image description here
Image for explanation. I used the =days(end,begin) formula to calculate the number of days that has lapsed since servicing. HOW DO I HIDE THE 45396 number?????? Super beginner to excel, just learning formulas.

Something like:
=IF(OR(begin="",end=""),"",DAYS(begin,end))

